# Question about a specific filming technique - the long zoom

Tags: film-techniques

This scene, which I can't find anywhere but on a Facebook page, contains one long zoom taking up approximately 50 - 70 feet.  Can anyone suggest how it might have been done (considering the time period), or a way to replicate it with simple equipment?

The movie is called [Les Ailes (1927)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wings_(1927_film)) (aka Wings), and the scene in question is here:

https://www.facebook.com/senscritique/videos/10153456242162987/

Comment: Man, that's a beautiful shot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not a zoom at all. You can tell the difference between a zoom and a dolly shot by how the background changes.

Zooms are shots using the camera lens to change the magnification of the image.  Here's a video that explains it:

This is definitely a dolly shot. You can see how people sit back in their chairs as the camera approaches to let it pass.  To be clear, it's either a [crane shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crane_shot) with a large crane or a crane shot on a dolly with a small crane. Huge studio spaces allow for use of large equipment of the time.

Something similar to this but with an overhead arm:

[image: Early film era crane on dolly]

And here's what a giant crane would look like (from 1934):

[image: Giant crane from 1934]

Comment: That video on the difference between zoom and dolly is fascinating.  I don't know if I ever consciously picked up on the difference between the two.

Comment: There's also the *jib* that fills the gap between a dolly and a full crane. And then there's the arial photography.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, did you mean "aerial"? Arial is a font.

Comment: @DangerZone Ugh, yes. Errr.. maybe I meant the mermaid?

Comment: @ToddWilcox That's "Ariel" :P

Comment: @DangerZone They should have named her "Helvetica".

Comment: And, of course, combining the dolly shot with an opposite zoom yields the iconic [dolly zoom](https://vimeo.com/84548119) effect.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Also known as the "creepy" dolly zoom effect :P

Comment: And for completeness, a "dolly zoom" is a shot that combines both techniques, working against each other, so that the subject stays the same size and the background (and foreground, if present) change around it. EDIT: Hey, three people posted the same thing at the same time, what are the odds?